# Get URL parameter and pass to form select in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, parameters, parameter-passing

I need to get a parameter from URL and select an option based on that parameter.

This is the code that just worked until I have updated Contact Form 7 plugin:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['location'])) {
    $parameter = $_GET['location'];
    echo $parameter;
} else {
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#location').find('option[data-url=<?php echo $parameter; ?>]').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

WP code:

```
<select onchange="location=this.value;" id="location">
    <option readonly>Select your location</option>

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => '8',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'ID'
        );
    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

    <option value="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/meet-the-fleet/?location=<?php the_title(); ?>" data-url="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

</select>
```

All the above code should do the trick, but after that update is not working anymore, even if in this case is not used for CF7 plugin... is just for a standalone select. It might be jQuery related?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem was when the jQuery was loaded. It needed to be loaded before my code, not after, buy I am not understanding why before the CF7 update has worked just fine...